# jQuery responsive columns.

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

We are working with a responsive design and we want to make responsive columns.
So on large screens items will be stored in 2 columns and on small in one. Items could have different height. Items should be placed in the right order (see the image below).

[image: items order]

**1. From 1 -> 2**

One column layout:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

Script that transformation it to two columns.

```
$(".container > .item:odd").wrapAll('<div class="column" />');
$(".container > .item").wrapAll('<div class="column" />');
```

**2. From 2 -> 1**

Two columns layout:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Script that transformation it to the one column.

```
while($(".container .column .item").length > 0)
      {
        $(".container").append($(".container .column:eq(0) .item:first"))
        $(".container").append($(".container .column:eq(1) .item:first"))
      }
$(".container2 .column1").remove();
```

We can't use $(".container item").unwrap() for second option, cause it will not *save items order*.

Everything works but we wonder if there is any solution that will be easier (especially for the 2 option). We will appreciate for any suggestion or help.

Comment: have you considered not using jQuery at all and go with CSS media queries?

Comment: Check out [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) I used it on a couple of big projects and it's working out great ;)

Comment: DA - how it could be done with media queries? Actualy we use them as breakpoints on which to perform the transformation.

Comment: Miha Rekar - yes it helps but it doesn't save order of items. it tries to make two columns of one height.

Comment: Have you seen Masonry.js? http://masonry.desandro.com/ Maybe that will work for you.

Comment: Ed Charbeneau - yes, but it doesn't preserve items order.